# How to access view items inside a ListView android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have `ListView`. i am successfully able to populate that `ListView` but what is want now is when user long press on `ListItem` it should make a button visible which i made invisible when i am populating `ListView`.

here is snippet i have tried.

mItemListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterview, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            LinearLayout view=(LinearLayout) mItemListView.getChildAt(arg2);
            view.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

My adapter is extending `BaseAdapter`

Comment: arg1 in onItemLongClick is your clicked item so retrive your button using findViewById from this arg1 view

Comment: @Satya thanks dear i did exactly what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use View that is passed to your `onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterview, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3)` method. For example

```
mItemListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterview, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
          arg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks buddy got an idea from your answer and my problem is no more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this button is part of the layout in the linear layout that is populated in each list item ? In that case use `view.findViewById(id_of_your_button)` and get the button view and set **that** to VISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter to redraw the list. Be careful though, if you're setting the button to invisible inside the getView method of the adapter, this will reverse the visibility back to invisible.

You should probably use a separate array holding the visibility state of each button, toggle that state, and use it to set the button state when drawing.